# How to prevent css libraries like tailwindcss and bootstrap to effect wysiwyg editor's html content (like Tinymce,Ckeditor)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, tinymce, tailwind-css

Having a TinyMCE-Editor, it gives me as output proper html tags like h1, h2, b, ul, ol, li.
Like this:

[image]

However, when I want to render exactly the output of TinyMCE in my own frontend, which is consisting of TailWindCSS or Bootstrap, every style of every html-tag looks very plain with same size, same margin, same padding, as it would be in a normal text-element.

[image]

I found out, that these CSS-frameworks use something like "normalize-css" to achieve this look. However, how can I restore the CSS-styles of TinyMCE in my frontend although I am using Tailwind and/or BootstrapCSS?

Comment: Can you confirm that the content you are rendering in the second screenshot has the same HTML as the editor content? Said another way, can you confirm that the HTML content from TinyMCE is being retained, and that you are not rendering plain text content?

Comment: yes! Definitely. It has the same html. But due to normalize-css, which is part of TailwindSS and Bootstrap, it will be normalized to this

Answer (score 4):

I use @layer of tailwindcss to define base, like this:

```js
// tailwind.scss
@tailwind base;

@layer base {
  // define revert css here
  .no-tailwindcss-base {

    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
      font-size: revert;
      font-weight: revert;
    }

    ol,
    ul {
      list-style: revert;
      margin: revert;
      padding: revert;
    }
  }
}

@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Then you can set a className that you defined on your render element. Like this:

```html
<div class="no-tailwindcss-base" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I must say, my answer won't be very different from the answer given by Zhongxu. The thing is, I am not familiar with @layer directive, and the provided answer was essentially not working for me. Therefore, I'll leave below the CSS styles that I've come up with to solve the mystery, but the credit goes to @Zhongxu:

```css
@tailwind base;

@layer base {

    .no-tailwindcss-base h1,
    .no-tailwindcss-base h2,
    .no-tailwindcss-base h3,
    .no-tailwindcss-base h4,
    .no-tailwindcss-base h5,
    .no-tailwindcss-base h6 {
        font-size: revert;
        font-weight: revert;
    }

    .no-tailwindcss-base ol,
    .no-tailwindcss-base ul {
        list-style: revert;
        margin: revert;
        padding: revert;
    }
}

@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

```html
<div class="no-tailwindcss-base">
   <!-- Other elements here-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Small modification for @TheFaultInOurStars solution. This will reduce the code and apply no-tailwindcss-base to all children

```css
@layer base {
    .no-tailwindcss-base, .no-tailwindcss-base * , .no-tailwindcss-base > * {
        font-size: revert;
        font-weight: revert;
        margin: revert;
        display: revert;
        vertical-align: revert;
        max-width: revert;
        height: revert;
        border-width: revert;
        border-style: revert;
        border-color: revert;
        outline: revert;
        list-style: revert;
        padding: revert;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Talwind Preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight) is responsible for this. Preflight removes all the margins, paddings and every set of base styles.

```
@tailwind base; /* Preflight will be injected here */

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

You can disable it

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
   preflight: false,
  }
}
```

**Once disabled**, html tags like h1, h2, b, ul, ol, li will be rendered properly.

Comment: OP wants to disable it only for tinymce content.

Answer (score 1):

The "unreset" approach from swyx worked for me ( https://gist.github.com/sw-yx/28c25962485101ca291ec1947b9d0b3e )

1. Paste in the unrest class into your css (or have mix build it in)
2. Put the html from TinyMCE into a div and use the unrest class

```
<div class="unreset">
    {!! $tinyMCEhtmloutput !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in the same problem but I found a way. This way works for me and is the simplest way. Note I am also using tailwind css with django summernote editor (works on any editor) and I will use ul and li as only disc in my working template so in my HTML template file, I added:

```html
<style> ul{   list-style-type: disc; } </style>
```

I know this may not work if you want to add many ul li elements as 1,2,3 or I II III, but it works. At least Its better than editing root files or config files (as they are not beginner friendly).Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use tailwindcss, you can use the [typography-plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin) and simply add the `prose` class e.g:

```js
<article class="prose lg:prose-xl">
  <h1>Garlic bread with cheese: What the science tells us</h1>
  <!-- ... -->
</article>
```

Answer (score -1):

// i think this must work... hopefully..
@tailwind base;

@layer base {

no-tailwindcss-base{

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6`enter code here`{
  list-style: revert;
  margin: revert;
  padding: revert;
}
```

}
}

@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.