# Django-Tinymce with Tailwind CSS

Tags: django, npm, tailwind-css, tinymce-4

I am currently using django-tinymce4-lite for my project and everything else works as expected. But on the actual rendered HTML page where the tinymce4 formatted content is supposed to be displayed, tailwind-preflight messes up the formatting with lists and spaces.

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66180213/how-to-render-html-coming-out-of-tinymce-with-proper-stylesheets-in-my-own-front). It is the exact problem I am facing. The first answer doesn't work for me and I want to get that working. I am following [this](https://medium.com/@lendinez/how-to-use-tailwind-in-django-and-not-die-in-the-attempt-2853eb164aa7) tutorial to use Tailwind CSS with Django. I am new to npm so I blindly followed, and everything works but when I try to implement the first answer nothing happens.

Using the second answer works but then it messes up the entire front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this probably will mess up your entire frontend (currently facing this myself).

Setting `preflight: false` in the Tailwind config will stop Tailwind running the preflight, which basically removes all base CSS styling (padding, size, underscores) for tags like `h1`, `a`, `li`, *etc*.

You can reapply all these in your frontend using Tailwind, but will have to do this. The CSS is what it is; you are telling Tailwind not to clear the base styling out, which means what you enter in Tinymce will appear how you expect it to.

Comment: Yes, I know that and I don't want to set `preflight: false` for the entire frontend. As I asked  I only want to be able to disable preflight for a certain div or maybe a possible way to negate preflight for a certain div.